# How to get jenkins to run my qunit test using phantomjs

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, qunit

Im working on getting our CI (Jenkins) to use and run our qunit test, we have qunit-reporter, qunit.compposite and phantomjs to execute the whole. Im not ant expert so im using windows batch command as a prestep with the following command

```
phantomjs src\test\webapp\js\runner.js src\test\webapp\jquery.all.test.html > test-report.xml
```

Now this runs and generates the junit xml file, with a few issues, firstly since I use pipe phantomjs performance information is also put into the file so that's my first issue

My second issue is that I have no idea in the world how I can get Jenkins to actually read the xml file instead of just considering it random stuff, similar to it interpreting when we have junit test run.

Just for reference the project is a maven project.

All advice is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins, **configure** your job, add a **post build action**, select publish JUnit test result report then add the path to your xml file in the requested field.

Answer (score 0):

A couple years ago, a colleague of mine and I worked on getting PhantomJS to run QUnit tests and output JUnit XML that Jenkins can consume:
http://www.cameronjtinker.com/post/2013/09/24/QUnit-JSCoverage-and-Jenkins.aspx

I had forgotten to post this on my blog after we worked on this so I just posted it today when I saw your question. Much has changed since 2011 when this was originally written, but it should have most of the same concepts involved.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, since there now is plugins that can do the xml out of the box, for me the part is getting Jenkins to read the xml file and make sense of it, so what you write in your blog as "From there, integration into Jenkins is fairly trivial." is the part i need help with :)

Comment: @JesperLind Where are the plugins that can write XML out of the box?

Comment: Hi Chris if you look here http://qunitjs.com/plugins/ basically the junit logger generates a xml output, which Is why I can just "pipe" the result from the phantomjs run into a file... hope this helps :D